# How to set message property without using JMS to create XML file

Tags: xml, jms, ibm-mq, xerces-c

Hi I am new to Websphere MQ C++, I need to know how to set message property without using JMS **msg.setStringPropery(" ", " ")**. I am using Xerces XML Parser btw. Please help me to solve this. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The V7 MQI features (MQSUB, Message Handles, properties etc.) were not incorporated into the V7 C++ classes. Furthermore, IBM has announced that the C++ classes are functionally stabilized.  That means they are still supported but no new function is being added to them.

You could wrap the MQI in your own C++ API if you want to use full function of WMQ calls - and not try to mix and match `ImqMessage` and `MQSETMP`. So you would use all of the C API calls, including `MQSETMP`, rather than using `ImqQueueManager` and etc and then trying to invoke just `MQSETMP`.

Either that or use the C++ Message Service Client and the `ImqMessage.setStringPropery` method.  The Message Service Client is basically the JMS API implemented in C++ so you have all the normal JMS facilities (like administered objects in a JNDI namespace, for example).  It is the "native" interface of WMQ C++ classes so it isn't clear why you would not want to use that.

Comment: I'm using Websphere MQ for C++ and we're not using JMS.